# Primefaces push to specific user

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, push

I've got Primefaces push successfully working for global paths, however I'm having some difficulty getting parameterized paths working. The idea is to push FacesMessages to individual users.

So I have in my index.xhtml:

```
<p:socket onMessage="handlePush" channel="/#{parliamentManager.user}" autoConnect="true" widgetVar="subscriber"/>
```

In ParliamentManager I get the user and connect to the channel:

```
@PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
      logger.log(Level.INFO,"Session started");
      ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
      Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();

      user = (User) sessionMap.get("user");
      logger.log(Level.INFO, "user trader is: {0}", 
              new Object[]{user.getTrader().getTraderId().toString()});

      RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
      requestContext.execute("alert('PostConstruct')");
      requestContext.execute("PF('subscriber').connect('/" + user + "')");
    }
```

In my RequestScoped Stateful bean where the validation occurs I attempt to push the message (with hardcoded user for now):

```
if((book.getPrice() * bidOrder.getAmount()) > bidOrder.getTrader().getBalance())
        {
            EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
            eventBus.publish("jimmy" , new FacesMessage("Error", "You have " + bidOrder.getTrader().getBalance() 
            + " and are trying to buy " + book.getPrice()*bidOrder.getAmount()));
            return;
        }
```

However my PushResource onMessage is never fired. I suspect I'm using the wrong syntax somewhere in my pushresource for the parameter or in the eventBus.publish message though I'm not sure what it should be:

PushResource:

```
@PushEndpoint("{user}")
@Singleton
public class PushResource
{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("politse.web.PushResource");

@PathParam("user")
private String user;

@OnMessage(decoders = JSONDecoder.class, encoders = JSONEncoder.class)
public void onMessage(RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus eventBus) {        
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "PushResource.onMessage user: {0}", 
            new Object[]{user});
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made a few mistakes in the initial code which became obvious when I added onOpen to my resource object and logged the channel name. Firstly my socket channel variable was pointing to a user entity object instead of the user ID. So I created the userId in ParliamentManager as a String property. This created a correctly named channel.

```
<p:socket onMessage="handlePush" channel="/#{parliamentManager.userId}" autoConnect="true" widgetVar="subscriber"/>
```

Also I don't need to connect to the channel if autoConnect=true, so I dropped that from ParliamentManager @PostConstruct. My encoder was also wrong, I changed it to accept the FacesMessage correctly.

```
@PushEndpoint("{user}")
@Singleton
public class PushResource
{

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("politse.web.PushResource");

@PathParam("user")
private String user;

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus eventBus) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "PushResource.onOpen endpoint: {0}", 
            new Object[]{r});
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(RemoteEndpoint r, EventBus eventBus) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "PushResource.onClose endpoint: {0}", 
            new Object[]{r});
}

@OnMessage(encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
public FacesMessage onMessage(FacesMessage message) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "PushResource.onMessage facesMessage");
    return message;
}

}
```

The EventBus publish code was actually correct and didn't need the additional slash.

Answer (score 0):

In eventBus.publish user without "/" may be in this problem

Comment: Thanks hekko, but I've tried that and it doesn't seem to solve the problem.